# Getting HTTP header from packet after TCP, IP and Ethernet headers removed

Tags: c, http, tcp, header

I am writing a packet sniffer and have the parsed the headers down to TCP, and was wondering how I would now go about getting the HTTP headers.

I have tried printing the packet data at this point, however this does not contain the HTTP header.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They must be there, in the TCP payload, surely?

Comment: I thought so to, put when I print each packets payload it is just the data and not the headers

Comment: So you've removed it.

Comment: Would I start printing the data from packet - size of all the headers?

Answer (score 0):

The http header is within the data obtained in the TCP packet, but you must convert this data correctly.